# How to get HTML from method call using spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java method foo, inside that i am calling another samplefoo method which should return model rendered html.

for that i made a jsp ("userresults") and given

**sample code:**

```
foo(){
samplefoo(model);
}

@ResponseBody
samplefoo(model){
model.addAttribute("sample","sample");
return "userresults";
}
```

.

i annotated @ResponseBody at the method samplfoo.

But still not getting the userresults renderd jsp in foo method.

can some one please helpl

Comment: `@ResponseBody` will tell spring to that a method return value should be bound to the web response body. i.e it doesn't add the model, view binding.  So it will not consider it as a jsp page, instead it will consider as a  response String.

Comment: Can you pleas suggest what i can do to get the rendered html Pragnani Kinnera

Comment: Remove `@ResponseBody` annotation and you need to make sure to have a request mapping to your view. And also it will render your jsp only when they exist in your WEB-INF directory. If you wnat them in separate place you need to have a Resource View Resolver

Answer (score 0):

You call samplefoo from a method inside the same class.
In these cases there is no proxy or interceptor from spring involved.
So there is nothing handling your annotation.